# How can I create the same functionality of onsubmit="return groupAdd()" when dynamically adding the onsubmit with an EventHandler?

Tags: javascript, html, eventhandler

Use to just add an `onclick` event with a `button` and collect data, did not even need a `form element`, but with `HTML5` you can take advantage of error check and default messages displayed when a user submits a form.

```
<input type="email" id="addEmail" name="addEmail"  placeholder="user@sample.com" value="" required="" title="" />
```

Since the type is `email` and there is a `require` attribute present the browser will check for a well structured email address `onsubmit`. If the value fails a message appears under the input indicating the user must fix the value.

You can also use regular expression for example

```
<input type="password" id="addPassword" name="addPassword"  placeholder="Password" value="" required="" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$"  title="" />
```

All together you have

```
<script>
function userAdd(){
    *** xmlhttprequest code *******
    return false;
}
</script>

<html>
<form action="admin" method="post" onsubmit="return userAdd();">
<input type="email" id="addEmail" name="addEmail"  placeholder="user@sample.com" value="" required="" title="" />
<input type="password" id="addPassword" name="addPassword"  placeholder="Password" value="" required="" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$"  title="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

When I generate the form element dynamically I need to attach an event handler:

```
f = document.createElement('form');

addEventHandler(f,'submit', function(){userAdd()});

function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
     if (elem.addEventListener)
         elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
     else if (elem.attachEvent)
         elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
    }
}
```

The reason I want to keep the default submit functionality is because of the built in HTML5 features.

How can I create the same functionality of onsubmit="return groupAdd()" when dynamically adding the unsubmit with an EventHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML5 with DOM2 API:

> f.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { if (!userAdd()) {
>   e.preventDefault(); } });